# How can I mount local folder as SMB folder

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina

How can I mount local folder as SMB/ AFP share locally?

For example:

I have folder `/tmp/myLocalFolder`
I want to create `smb` share to `/tmp/myLocalFolder` at location `/tmp/myShareLocalFolder`

How can I do it (in Mojave/Catalina)?

Comment: Not sure `/tmp` can be easily shared via SMB, but folders in `/Users/youruser` may. What kind of problem are you trying to solve with this, what have you tried so far to get it working?

Comment: I looking for a way to share locally a folder (it's less important which folder) without root (style of open local server on 127.0.0.1:8080 on a specific folder)

Comment: It's o.k. to use SMB/AFP as long as it doesn't required root or username:password of my account